# Setting of CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK variable in Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django-forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am referring to this: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/install.html. I would like to use Django Crispy Forms together with Twitter Bootstrap, hence i need to set
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK to bootstrap.

Where do i do this? I am not sure how to do this.. Need some guidance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'
```

it goes in your settings.py.

Comment: For Bootstrap 3 use: `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'`

Comment: And, perhaps unsurprisingly, for Bootstrap 4 use `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`

Answer (score 1):

```
 CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

It should be added to your settings.py file in your root directory